# What does this 'number' function do?

Tags: c, function, output

I had this question in an exam - http://ideone.com/uMausI

The code is -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int number(int n)
{

    if(n == 1)
    return n;
    int half = n/2;
    int k = 2*number(n/2) + half*half;
    return (n%2)?(k+n):k;

}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d",number(11));
    return 0;
}
```

I know *to solve these type of questions, one should understand what the FUNCTION is actually doing*. It saves you a lot of time because then you don't have to run for each case(which can take significantly longer time). I instead ran the case and found the result. So, I want to know **what this 'number' function actually does? If it does something meaningful like calculating square or something like that**. I couldn't find a generic answer to it.

Comment: Function quoted calculates a value of recursive expression of one argument.

Comment: It's a recursive function

Comment: @Basilevs I don't see a reason to downvote this!

Comment: Have you tried to run the program ?

Comment: The function takes an int and returns an int.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I have share a 'ideone' link which runs it & yes I have created that link myself.

Comment: Looks like some kind of Geometric Series

Comment: @halkujabra : modify your main program : `int i; for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) printf("%d    %d\n",i, number(i));`, run it and then you will see what is does actually.

Comment: @Ajay If you read between the lines, you will discover my comment is suggesting this question should be closed( unclear what you are asking ), since you have a high reputation, please do so.

Comment: @Ajay and everyoneelse - I think looking at answers will tell you that this question makes sense. Fuuh! People flaunting & misusing their repo by downvoting valid & good questions on Stackoverflow! Well guys, Stackoverflow is run by community if you realise it. Huh!

Comment: I didn't down vote! I didn't initially close it either, but now voted for closure. Answer given by @ravi is excellent. But, again, IMO, the question wasn't formed well! :) `return n<2 ? n : (n+number(n-1));` would be more straight solution.

Comment: @Ajay That's not a reason to close a good question. Also, I gave it as it was given in the exam. Maybe it was just to confuse people.

Comment: @halkujabra Gave you +1 to offset the haters, but I think this is more a question for [Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a recursive function to calculate the sum of n natural numbers where 'n' is the input to recursive function.

Had you tried with some sample inputs you would have deduced it easily. Below are some samples:-

Input   Output

2         3

5         15

7         28

10        55

Mathematical formula for calculating the sum of n natural numbers is:-

```
( n * ( n + 1 ) ) / 2
```

Explanation ( thanks to molbdnilo ):-

SUppose you want to sum the numbers from 1 to 100.

```
Compute (1 + 100) + (2 + 99) + (3 + 98) + ... + (98 + 3) + (99 + 2) + (100 + 1) = 
           101 + 101 + ... + 101 = 100 * 101 = 10100.
```

Since every number occurs twice in the summation, the sum you're looking for is

```
10100/2 = 5050;
```

the sum is

```
n*(n+1)/2.
```

(If you calculate `2*sum(n/2)` for an even number 'n', you'll notice that it is `(nn + 2n)/4`, while `sum(n)` is `(2*nn + 2*n)/4)`. 
Add n*n/4 to 2*sum(n/2) and you get `sum(n)`).

EDITED IN RESPONSE TO COMMENTS:-

@halkujabra molbdnilo has given good explanation.

@Jonathan:- No Integers include whole range of numbers on number line ( numbers without fractional part )

```
... -100, -50 , 0 , 50 ,100...
```

Whole numbers are non-negative integers i.e

```
0, 50, 100
```

Natural numbers :- whole numbers - 0 , i.e

```
1, 50, 100
```

Comment: That's the answer here! Hey, I can't seem to relate the formula to solution. Can you help me with it?

Comment: @ravi I can see the pattern you describe by "(n * (n + 1)) /2" but I don't know what you mean: "Mathematical formula for calculating the sum of n natural numbers is" Natural Numbers are just `int`s: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number

Comment: @halkujabra SUppose you want to sum the numbers from 1 to 100. Compute (1 + 100) + (2 + 99) + (3 + 98) + ... + (98 + 3) + (99 + 2) + (100 + 1) = 101 + 101 + ... + 101 = 100 * 101 = 10100. Since every number occurs twice in the summation, the sum you're looking for is 10100/2 = 5050; the sum is n*(n+1)/2.  (If you calculate 2*sum(n/2) for an even number n, you'll notice that it is (n*n + 2n)/4, while sum(n) is (2*n*n + 2*n)/4). Add n*n/4 to 2*sum(n/2) and you get sum(n)).

Comment: @molbdnilo Excellent explanation. It makes sense now thank you.

Comment: @JonathanMee Please see my explanation above...Hope I am clear

Comment: @ravi Will upvote if you can include a summary of [molbdnilo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/404970/molbdnilo)'s explanation in your answer; cause that's what clarified it for me.

Comment: @JonathanMee Did it.... Maybe it would help others also

Answer (score 2):

It's calculating using this decomposition:

[image: picture of triangles]

Clearly, the n-th triangle number is `2*number(n/2) + (n/2)*(n/2)`, plus the final line which gets added in the odd case (ie. the purple line is `+n` if `n % 1`).

Comment: @NicholasWilson Can you give me some math explaining what in the world you just proved?

Comment: @JonathanMee Even I am totally blank on this!

Comment: @NicholasWilson So you're saying that the purple is added to support the fractional part is added to account for C's round down on `int` division.

Comment: @halkujabra OK, so what I'm getting out of this is if you make a square of sides 11 (or whatever you want to pass into `number`) and then you cut it in half diagonally, but you include each unit on the diagonal, you'll get this number.

Comment: @JonathanMee absolutely correct! interesting result